# Sending `time` command into text file

Tags: io-redirection, output, time-utility

I want to get the result of `time` command into a text file but it's not working it only put blank space in the text file.

I already tried this commands,

A-

```
$ x=`time`
$ echo $x > log.txt
$ cat log.txt

$
```

B-

```
$ time > log.txt

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$ cat log.txt

$
```

C-

```
$ time > log.txt 2>&1

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

$ cat log.txt

$
```

What I really want is this.

```
$ time > log.txt
$ cat log.txt

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the external [`time`](http://www.gnu.org/software/time/) command instead of the builtin:

```
/usr/bin/time -po log.txt true
\time -po log.txt true   # simpler way
```

For example:

```
$ \time -po log.txt true
$ cat log.txt
real 0.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
```